# Azure Data Factory (ADF) "copy Activity". Setting default values for missing data loading from CSV Blob to Azure MySQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a source CSV in blob container. I need to load it to Azure MySQL table.

In the CSV, there are some missing fields for various columns. How can I set default values for different columns in the "Copy Data" activity ?

I don't want to involve "Data Flows", or any transformation activity in the pipeline for now. Just want to see if it can be done with basic copy activity ? Or is it not possible ?

Example: missing "date_value_columnA" to be defaulted to "9999-99-99"; missing "string_value_columnB" to be defaulted to "string value not availabe"...something along these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Copy Data activity is intended to copy data "as is" and cannot change columns on the way. That can be done in the Data Flows activity.

If you only want to use Copy Data, you can copy the CSV to an stg table on Azure MYSQL, and then use a script or a stored procedure to make the transformation you need and load it into the destination table.

Another option, if all your transformations are adding defaults to missing values, is to use constraints on the destination table, to add a value when the received value is null. This option is harder to manage in the long run, especially if you have a lot of columns, so option 1 (script\stored procedure) is probably better.

Comment: ok thank you for the response :) just wanted to see if it was a possibility.